# Can a local constraint evaluate a local lambda?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

[Consider](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TY8z57znE):

```
int main() {
    auto f = [](unsigned x) { return x == sizeof(int); };
    return []<class T>(T) requires (f(sizeof(T))) { return 99; }(12);
}
```

Clang<sup>13.0.0 5f6b3d1</sup> and MSVC<sup>19.29.29917</sup> accept; gcc<sup>11.0.1 20210407</sup> rejects complaining that `f` is not captured:

```
In substitution of 'template<class T> main()::<lambda(T)> [with T = int]':
3:65:   required from here
3:12:   required by the constraints of 'template<class T> main()::<lambda(T)>'
3:38: error: 'f' is not captured
    3 |     return []<class T>(T) requires (f(sizeof(T))) { return 99; }(12);
      |                                    ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, if `f` is captured explicitly (either by value or by reference) gcc *still* complains that it is not captured ‍♀️:

```
error: 'f' is not captured
    3 |     return [f]<class T>(T) requires (f(sizeof(T))) { return 99; }(12);
      |                                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
                   ~^~ what's this then?
```

And if a capture-default is provided (either `&` or `=`) gcc ices:

```
3:39: internal compiler error: trying to capture 'f' in instantiation of generic lambda
    3 |     return [&]<class T>(T) requires (f(sizeof(T))) { return 99; }(12);
      |                                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
0x1cfdb99 internal_error(char const*, ...)
0x7ffd56 add_capture(tree_node*, tree_node*, tree_node*, bool, bool)
0x8000ea add_default_capture(tree_node*, tree_node*, tree_node*)
0x73f30a constraints_satisfied_p(tree_node*, tree_node*)
0x954dc3 fn_type_unification(tree_node*, tree_node*, tree_node*, tree_node* const*, unsigned int, tree_node*, unification_kind_t, int, conversion**, bool, bool)
0x6e258e build_op_call(tree_node*, vec<tree_node*, va_gc, vl_embed>**, int)
0x980f05 finish_call_expr(tree_node*, vec<tree_node*, va_gc, vl_embed>**, bool, bool, int)
0x8e173d c_parse_file()
0xa60682 c_common_parse_file()
```

Is this a bug in gcc (well, apart from the ice), or are MSVC and clang wrong to accept?

Comment: Interesting; lambdas have a rewrite rule for id-expressions, maybe gcc doesn't extend that properly to requires-clauses? See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-11 it only applies to the compound-statement

Comment: That requires-clause is also an unevaluated context, which means no ODR-use happens... https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#9

Comment: This is apparently gcc bug since `f(sizeof(T))` is a [constant expression](https://godbolt.org/z/Po7hK5dGe).

Comment: Have you reported the ICE yet?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I have now: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99994